# Open new activities OnImageButton click

Tags: android, android-activity, imagebutton

I'm trying to create an activity with several buttons and I want that on click they open a new activity. I tried this code but it does not seem to work (I click the Puntos Image and nothing happens) Do you see what could be wrong?

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

   ImageButton puntos;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);    
      puntos = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ImagePuntos);
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       if(arg0.getId() == R.id.ImagePuntos){

           Intent openActivity1 = new Intent(MainMenu.this, MisPuntos.class);
           startActivity(openActivity1);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml layout, where you define **ImagePuntos**, give it the attribute

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Comment: Used your advice and works like a charm! In a few moments I'll be able to accept your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wonderful. I gave you the easier fix, because it was faster to check. On the programmatic way you'd have to add the OnClickListener import, set a new OnClickListener, embed the existing onClick method into the OnClickListener, ... too boring! And you now have a method which is **shareable with other controls** (you just have to add a switch case selector to get the id of the clicked item and react properly).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that either the ImageButton has it's onClick attribute set to onClick in the XML or set it programmatically by adding `puntos.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: +1 since i consider this approach much more MVC. the onclick attribute is ok, and android team uses it,  but i don't like to let the view know anything about the controller.

Comment: @CarlosRobles I completely agree and don't like to use the XML attribute for this reason.